# About an Angular6+ File Manager or the faced challenges?

Tags: javascript, angular

pretty sure anybody get to a point where you're asked big work and little time...
On my job I was asked to build a File Manager component for an Angular 6+ platform.
Right now, I'm on design fase. Do you know of any good "plug-in" component that I might use and save a lot of work?

Or at least, some challenges I might face and other things I should pay attention to?

I must craft a component as flexible as possible, and with Drag'n Drop feature.

Any help I could get will be a lifesaver.. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout - [ng-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload). If you just want drag n drop then checkout [ngx-file-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop)